# A tighter bound than Markov Inequality

Tags: probability-theory

Is there any way to find a tighter bound than Markov inequality?
For example, I know that if always $X>b>0$, we can define $Y=X-b$ and have a tighter bound. Is there any similar solution that uses/applies a restriction on the random variable for example their independence or other moments?

Comment: Have you heard about [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality) or [Chernoff bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound)?

Comment: "anyway" is a perfectly respectable word, but it doesn't mean the same thing as "any way".  (Although I've seen this usage a number of times.)  I changed it above.

Comment: I know about Chebyshev's inequality, but don't know how to use Chernoff in this case. As I think Chernoff bound is for sum of random variable not just a random variable.

Answer (score 3):

If
$$
X= \begin{cases} a & \text{with probability }p, \\ 0 & \text{with probability }1-p, \end{cases}
$$
then $\mathbb E X= ap$, and although Markov's inequality says $\Pr(X\ge a) \le\dfrac{\mathbb E X}{a}$, for this distribution we have exact equality.

I suspect it's easy to show (so I'm being momentarily lazy . . . ) that for all other distributions, the inequality is strict.  That would mean for all other distributions, a tighter bound exists.  But that tighter bound would not be a bound that is true of *all* distributions of non-negative-valued random variables.  If you want one that applies to *all* such distributions, this example shows a bound on how tight you can make it.

Comment: About laziness: recall that Markov inequality is nothing but the integrated version of the pointwise inequality $a\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant a}\leqslant X$. Hence the only equality case is indeed $X=a\times$ some Bernoulli, as you say.

Comment: I agree that having a tighter bound may restrict the applicability of the bound. But I want to know these restriction and see if it applies in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of [Concentration of measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_measure) as a more general way of thinking about concentration inequalities. One common case is when your random variables are sub-gaussian which is related to the higher moment stuff that you mentioned. See also [Bernstein inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_%28probability_theory%29).